# Sql query for clubbing the data according to date

Tags: mysql

[image: Table]

I have a table like this. Now I want to show the total of same dates of different status in single row.
What should be the query?

Expected Result

```
Created | Total1 | Total2 | Total3

2017-02-28 | 1 | 1 | 2
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: this is the image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKzs1.png

Comment: They didn't ask for a link to an image, but to the **expected result**

Comment: Date              total_draft     total_private      total_published

2017-02-28     1                       1                    2

Comment: you have only 3 story_status  (and are always the same)  or the story_status  can be more ??

Comment: No story_status is fixed

Comment: This should be the expected result                                                                               


Date              total_draft           total_publish          total_draft

2017-02-28           1                         2                            1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a sum for case when for each status and group by

```
select 
      created
    , sum( case when story_status ='Draft' then total else 0 end ) as Draft_count
    , sum( case when story_status ='Private' then total else 0 end ) as Private_count
    , sum( case when story_status ='Published' then total else 0 end ) as Published_count
from my_table 
group by created
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you one row per date created, with columns for each story_status:

```
SELECT
    `created`,
    SUM(if(`story_status` = 'Draft',`total`,0)) as `Total Draft`,
    SUM(if(`story_status` = 'Private',`total`,0)) as `Total Private`,
    SUM(if(`story_status` = 'Published',`total`,0)) as `Total Published`
FROM table
GROUP BY `created`
ORDER BY `created`
```